# Objective-C / iPhone IRC Library

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is there a IRC library that is suitable for use on the iPhone?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is Chat Core, used by Colloquy and Mobile Colloquy. It uses the new style BSD license.

[http://colloquy.info/project/wiki/Source Code](http://colloquy.info/project/wiki/Source%20Code)

Comment: View the source code here: http://colloquy.info/project/browser/trunk


In particular 'Chat Core' and 'Mobile Colloquy'

Answer (score 4):

You can try [libircclient](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libircclient/files/). It's written in c. There is also talk about a [cocoa wrapper](http://libircclient.sourceforge.net/cocoa/doc/html/index.html) for libircclient, but i don't know how well that works.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something in Swift, I'm writing a minimal lib, you can find in:

https://github.com/eugenio79/GMIRCClient